# Can I monitor my phones temperature?

Tags: settings

Recently in the UK we've had an unexpected bout of nice weather which means wherever I leave my phone it tends to get quite warm. I know the operating range of my phone (Sony Ericsson Arc) however is there an easy way to find out how warm it is?

It's never left in the sun, always in the shade. If I need to root it I'm open to options - currently running stock 2.3.4 Android.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [TempMonitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.alldroid.apps.tempmonitor&hl=en) available from Google Play Store:

> System temperature reading in your status bar updating at your choice interval.
>
> TempMonitor is the oldest CPU Temperature monitoring app on the android market. This app is built to do one thing: Temperature, and it does it well.

[image]

### Some features that you might like:

The temperature can be displayed on the status bar or in the APP Screen. You can also select what you want to see:

> - Choose from Celsius or Fahrenheit.
> - Choose what temperature to display (Battery, CPU).
> - Choose the update interval.

Comment: You must, however, note that most devices don't have a temperature sensor. Only a battery temperature sensor, so it may not work.

Comment: @liamwli Yes, the APP will only work if there's hardware to extract the information from **:)** I'm not 100% sure, but I believe that this phone (Sony Ericsson Arc) only comes with a battery sensor. Still, is better to know some than knowing nothing :)

Comment: The app is no longer available on play store, do you have the apk of this app?

Comment: Note that the app is not available on the Play Store anymore, so future readers might have a difficulty in downloading it (you may still be able to see the entry on the Play Store if you have installed it before).

Answer (score 0):

[Battery Temperature Guard free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=src.schimi.temperatureguardfree) is another cool app to monitor your Android's battery temperature. This will warn you if it gets too high.

This app was very useful during my summer vacation in south France :-)

Comment: Note that the app is not available on the Play Store anymore, so future readers might have a difficulty in downloading it (you may still be able to see the entry on the Play Store if you have installed it before).